# java.lang.AssertionError when trying to switch frames in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to switch from one frame to another using the following code:

> user.switchFrame(authorPagebjects.frameId);

where switchFrame() is a method defined in another class like this:

```
if (keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("switchFrame")) {
    if (element instanceof WebElement)
        driver.switchTo().frame((WebElement) element);
        assertTrue(element + "\" does not exist", false);
}
```

However, on running the test I am getting the following error:

```
va.lang.AssertionError: Proxy element for: org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator@70a36a66" does not exist
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at com.wcms.methods.ActionMethods.actionKeys(ActionMethods.java:57)
    at com.wcms.methods.ActionKeyword.switchFrame(ActionKeyword.java:37)
    at com.wcms.test.AuthorPage.createTemplateTest(AuthorPage.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

However, on using `driver.switchTo().frame(authorPagebjects.frameId);` the above error is not appearing. But I want to define the switchFrames() method in another class only.

Can you please advise on what's going wrong here? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is `element` in your method switchFrame? Why are u switching to element instead of frame whose id u have passed?

Comment: I am passing the frame Id itself in the element

Comment: can u please show the switchFrame() method pls?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. It worked if we remove  the if statement, 'if (element instanceof WebElement)' altogether. Thanks for your advise!